# Magento 2 backend session timeout

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, backend, session

In Magento 1.x the backend session timeout was set via:
`Backend -> System -> Configuration -> Admin -> Security -> Session Lifetime (seconds)`

Initially, my question was how to set this in Magento 2.0, but apparently there are differences between Magento 2.0 and Magento 2.1

For Magento 2.0: Arkadii Chyzhov has pointed out how to set this (see below).

For Magento 2.1: fschmengler has suggested a solution (see below).

However, M 2.1 appears not to provide a straightforward solution via the backend. 
Can anybody come up with an additional solution for M 2.1?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

> Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Admin
>   Session Lifetime (seconds)

Also, there is a possibility to set this parameter directly to the database, just put a value under the path

> admin/security/session_lifetime

in the table **core_config_data**

**Update**

> Magento 2.1 admin cookie life time =
>   Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Admin
>   Session Lifetime (seconds)
>   **or** till the user closes the browser

Since **Magento 2.1** introduces lifetime for admin cookie as "expires on browser close", **together with** value in

```
Stores >Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)
```

That means, that session lifetime equals the value in

```
Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)
```

or when a browser is closed.

Or you can set up a new value for admin cookie like it is proposed in [fschmengler's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/136594/32972)

Comment: would you be interested in adjusting the functionality of the layered navigation on our M2 website?

Comment: @ElsdenIep pls. find my contact information in the profile

Comment: Do you know what is the column in the database for that value, so I can change it programmatically?

Comment: I've set it to be 50400 but it still logs out after around 20 mins....

Comment: @ArkadiiChyzhov see my answer below :)

Answer (score 20):

Check attached image screenshot for better understanding of admin process.

Go to Stores->Settings->Configuration->Advanced->Admin->Security->Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)

And check screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 14):

### Solution for Magento 2.1+

Since Magento 2.1 the admin session lifetime is always "session", i.e. until the browser is closed. This <del>has been</del> might have been introduced for security reasons.

The relevant code is in `Magento\Backend\Model\Session\AdminConfig`:

```
/**
 * Set session cookie lifetime to session duration
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function configureCookieLifetime()
{
    return $this->setCookieLifetime(0);
}
```

If you want to change this behavior, you can add a plugin for this class with the following interceptor method:

```
public function beforeSetCookieLifetime()
{
    $lifetime = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        \Magento\Framework\Session\Config::XML_PATH_COOKIE_LIFETIME,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    return [$lifetime, \Magento\Framework\Session\Config::COOKIE_LIFETIME_DEFAULT];
}
```

Where `$this->scopeConfig` should be an instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface`, injected via constructor parameter.

This way the cookie lifetime is used from configuration, just as in the frontend.

Note that the configuration in *Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin Security > Session Lifetime* does not have any effect on the cookies anymore! It is used to determine Redis session lifetime, so if you increase the cookie lifetime, you should also increase this value.

Comment: I am wondering if you could explain this security reason. 
From my point of view,  setting admin cookie lifetime to 0, brings discrepancy and not obvious behavior, if we are using 'admin/security/session_lifetime', which defines admin session life time, and which depends from 2.1 on cookie lifetime implicitly.

Comment: I assumed it is to prevent the case that an admin closes the window without "log out" and the any person getting access to the same pc is already logged in. This is not a major threat and I agree with you that it's a bad decision to make this "feature" this non obvious.

Comment: But I searched for the responsible commit now and found this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e33a0332f2286a011ded0c7b5fa4f7b13ea853f0#diff-1125ab4d6bb922453ef7e22b6176311a " MAGETWO-49092: Invalid Form Key on Admin login page" - it sounds more like a workaround to hide another bug with a more or less accidental and at least undocumented side effect.

Comment: There must be more going on, because my session is still expiring without closing my browser.

Comment: How this works? I'm new to M2, but AFAIK you cannot create plugin for protected functions, and `before` plugin can only affect parameters, but `configureCookieLifetime` does not uses any.

Comment: @Volvox look carefully: the plugin is for `setCookieLifetime`, a public method with parameters

Answer (score 8):

A note here, the accepted answer works however magento 2 uses the default php folder to store session files, if you have this configured in php:

```
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean
```

then this is added to the system cron by the php installation.

So then you can either

- disable that cron
- or better: increase `gc_maxlifetime` in php.ini (as this will be the upper limit)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution without modifying any settings is to install any  `auto-refresh addon` for your browser and set its time (60 seconds).

It will auto-refresh the page for every 60 seconds which prevents session lifetime to expire and we can start working on another tab.

I used `Easy Auto Refresh` and it works fine for me.

Comment: dont be silly with such "solutions". its totally unacceptable.

Comment: It is acceptable if you can't change the settings on your server becaues your hoster does not allow it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why but for some of us setting the Admin Session Lifetime from backend doesn't work, so I found a couple of solutions:

1. In php.ini change session.gc_maxlifetime from 1440 to whatever number of seconds you desire. (This solution worked for me, tested on Magento 2.2.0 and 2.2.1)
2. In .htaccess add "php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 28800" or to whatever number of seconds you desire.
3. By manually setting the lifetime. Go to **vendor/magento/module-encryption-key/etc/config.xml** and change from 900s to whatever number of seconds you desire.

I hope one of these solutions will work for others too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using multiple VMs / servers for web and DB and the time is not synced also caused the issue.

So if all options above do not work, check the time stamp/date of the two severs when you are using multiple servers for web and DB.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the current value of the session.gc_maxlifetime PHP directive on your server, use the phpinfo() function

[image]

Need change from php.ini or something else..
 shows the path to the php.ini file that was used (see below). That will be the file to edit.
[image]