# Why admin gets logged out frequently?

Tags: magento-2.1.2

I am able to login in admin section, but the problem I am facing is that it logs out after some time.

The admin remains logged in for different time periods.

This is what I have done :

- Installed a magento 2.1.2 without sample data.
- Installed some of my modules and I started facing this issues.

I have a lot of modules. So what could possibly be wrong in my modules. How can I track a problem ?

I would like to know possible reasons for this problem. Thanks !

Comment: Because same admin details used by more than one person at a time. so you have to create unique user role for each user to prevent this issue.

Comment: @Rakesh : What if I tell you there is only one user using admin details.

Comment: not sure, may be check this once : http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-cookie-restriction-mode-guide-for-developers/

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101799/magento-2-backend-session-timeout check link

Comment: Admin is not even remaining logged in for the default 900 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the following setting in your admin panel

```
Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security
```

In **Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)** change value to 31536000 (One Year).

If you have multiple admins log to your admin panel the change

**Admin Account Sharing** to Yes