# Log out whenever styles are changed

Tags: magento2, session, grunt

Whenever I change less files in my current theme I get logged out from the backend.

- I'm using server-side compilation
- I'm using grunt with livereload.
- I'm in developer mode.

Both of them seem to work fine in themselves apart from the part where I get logged out.

Any ideas why this might be happening every single time?

Comment: You can take a look a the following link related to session timeout
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101799/magento-2-backend-session-timeout

Comment: Thanks @LedianHymetllari for the quick reply. I've already adjusted all the variables / configs related to session mentioned in that thread. It was the first one I found as well. I dont' get disconnected for hours if I don't make changes that require me to recompile styles. On the other side as soon as I edit a padding on my _extend.less file I get instant disconnection even if I've just logged in.

Comment: What commands are you running before you get logged out?

Comment: I'm just using grunt watch and uploading the new less file. My sequence is  grunt exec; grunt less; grunt watch

Answer (score 0):

These are separate features (admin session and less processor), so I suspect that your grunt configuration does something to the var folder/ clearing session database (memcache / redis..).

Check how are you storing session and make sure that your grunt command doesn't touch it.

Comment: I see, from what I could find session is in database and the grunt tasks are default as provided by magento. However I read somewhere that it could be because of signing static files option in configuration. I've set it to disabled and will test it out thoroughly today. So far it looks to be working as I haven't disconnected yet