# Magento Enterprise: Admin Logout Issue

Tags: magento-enterprise

Once we login into magento 1.14.x admin, It never logout automatically after sometime. I did check the admin settings `System->general - >Web->Session Cookie Management ->cookie lifetim`e is set to `3600`  `Cookie Path` and `Cookie Domain` is blank,so it is taking the default value. It was working all fine until we migrate from old server to new server The only change in server configuration is the new server is using web and data server separately

Answer (score 1):

You are checking at wrong place, you need to change the setting here,

```
System->Admin->Security
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: It is also setup 86400 seconds which should be 1 day , but Its been 5 days and the admin did not logged out

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/193843/2327 my guess was correct, It seems like the two server time does not sync and creating this issue